Proof P/B is a partition on set P
I ask your opinion about this proof i wrote for an exercise.
Given $P$ the set of all people and the relation $B=\{(p, q) \in P \times P | p\text{'s birthday is the same day of } q \text{'s}\}$, let $D$ be the set of all possible birthday dates, i need to demonstrate that $P/B = \{P_d | d \in D\}$ where P_d is the set of all people that have celebrate birthday on the day $d$.
Another given is that $B$ is an equivalence relation.
Proof:
Let $\{P_d | d \in D\}$ be $\mathcal{F}$, we want to demonstrate $P/B = \mathcal{F}$. To do this i can prove $P/B \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ and $ \mathcal{F} \subseteq P/B $.
We can pick an arbitrary $x \in P$.
$[x]_B$ contains all the people that have the same birthday, let's call it $d \in D$, as $x$. Hence, it exists a set $P_d$ so that $x \in P_d$ and being $x$ arbitrary we can conclude that $[x]_B \subseteq P_d$. Let's now pick an arbitrary $y \in P_d$, $y$ has the same birthday $d$ as $x$, so $y \in [x]_B$. Since y was arbitrary, we can conclude that $P_d \subseteq [x]_B$. $[x]_B \subseteq P_d$ and $P_d \subseteq [x]_B$ so $[x]_B = P_d$. $P_d \in \mathcal{F}$ and $[x]_B = P_d$ so $[x]_B \in \mathcal{F}$.
Let's take now an arbitrary $Y \in \mathcal{F}$. By definition $Y=\{y \in P d_1 \in D | y \text{'s birthday is the day } d1\}$ so every $y \in Y$ has the same birthday $d_1$. $[y]_B = \{x \in P | xRy \}$ and since B is reflexive $y \in [y]_B$ so, since $y$ was arbitrary, $Y \subseteq [y]_B$.
Now we take an arbitrary $x \in Y$, since every element of $Y$ has the same birthday, and every element of $[x]_B$ has the same birthday of $x$ and $x \in Y$, we can say, since $y \in Y$, $[x]_B = [y]_B$ and $[y]_B \subseteq Y$. Since $[y]_B \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq [y]_B$ then $[y]_B = Y$. Since $[y]_B = Y$ and $[y]_B \in P/B$ then $Y \in P/B$. $Y$ was an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{F}$, so $\mathcal{F} \subseteq P/B$.
We now have that $\mathcal{F} \subseteq {P/B}$ and $ P/B \subseteq \mathcal{F}$, so $P/B = \mathcal{F}$ $\square$.
Any opinion about this proof is very welcome, because i'm trying to understand how to write them and i learn best from experience rather than theory alone.
Thank you in advance for your time and have a nice xmas or whatever you celebrate this week(s) :).

Your construction of the set $Y$ is wrong. You cannot quantify $d$ like that inside of the set (for there is one $d$ for the whole set, not for each element of it)

@Malady, i see the error, i'm not sure how to construct it but i think i can leave it out because it's nature is implied by being a subset of F, right?

You wanna get better at writing proofs? Fix the error :)

This is false in general. If $P$ is empty then $P/B = {}$ but $\mathcal{F} = {{}}$. If you have an assumption on $P$ that makes this impossible, you should state it.

@Malady i think i can pick a $d_1\in D$ and use that to construct $Y={y \in P d_1 \in D | y \text{'s birthday is the day } d1}$

@NaïmFavier, i'm not really following: $P$ is the set of all people so it is implied to be non empty, is the implication that is wrong? should i explicity say that is not empty?

You should state exactly what is assumed of $P$. Being nonempty isn't enough: if everyone in $P$ is born on the same day then $P/B = {P}$ but $\mathcal{F} = {P, {}}$.

(Or rather, you should say what is expected of the "birthday" function $P \to D$. Hint: starts with an 's'.)

@NaïmFavier ah i think i got it now. I need to state that every $d \in D$ is a birthday to a $p$, otherwise $ \emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$ and this would make $\mathcal{F}$ not a partition. And this is the same as saying the function $P \rightarrow D$ is surjective. Am i correct?
